# yesod tutorial, nicEdit and a static gif-reference

Tags: haskell, yesod

Blog-example and the nicEditor on the tutorial on yesodweb work as they should. To learn something about yesod & scaffolding etc, I downloaded nicEdit, unzipped it, and put it into /static/js/nicEdit.js.

Then I edited Handler/Blog.hs and added the following there (modified a bit from Yesod.Form.Nic + some imports):

```
-- nicHtmlField2 :: YesodNic master => Field sub master Html
nicHtmlField2 = Field
    { fieldParse = \e _ -> return . Right . fmap (preEscapedText . sanitizeBalance) . listToMaybe $ e
    , fieldView = \theId name attrs val _isReq -> do
        toWidget [shamlet|
$newline never
    <textarea id="#{theId}" *{attrs} name="#{name}" .html>#{showVal val}
|]
        -- addScript' urlNicEdit
        addScript $ StaticR js_nicEdit_js
        -- addScript $ StaticR img_nicEditorIcons_gif
        master <- lift getYesod
        toWidget $
          case jsLoader master of
            BottomOfHeadBlocking -> [julius|
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function(){new nicEditor({fullPanel:true}).panelInstance("#        {rawJS theId}")});
|]
            _ -> [julius|
(function(){new nicEditor({fullPanel:true}).panelInstance("#{rawJS theId}")})();
|]
    , fieldEnctype = UrlEncoded
    }
  where
    showVal = either id (pack . renderHtml)
```

Then, entryForm to use the above function in the Handler/Blog.hs, after which

```
Settings.StaticFiles
```

into cabal,

```
/static StaticR Static getStatic
```

into config/routes  and touched Settings/StaticFiles.

If I recalled all the steps, the editor shows up now using local static javascript-file.

The problem is that static/js/nicEdit.js references nicEditorIcons.gif. At the moment, I do not know, how say to yesod, how to find the gif-file. The editor works and the buttons are there without any Icons. I tried to get them by adding a route to static icon file img_nicEditorIcons_gif. Now yesod log says yesod finds the icons. However, the icons are not visible in the nicEdit in the form.

I guess this is a basic thing, but couldn't find an answer to the problem ... so

1. Is it possible to refer to img_nicEditorIcons_gif in nicEdit.js directly? If so, how?
2. Is it possible to tell to yesod to let the nicEdit find the gif without editing the nicEdit.js-file (by using routes or handles or something)?
3. Use Shakespearean approach, put nicEdit.js contents to a julius-file and gif as a static route... which would mean that the js-file is not static anymore? Anyhow, I'll try this, too.

What I have discovered so far?

1. A change on nicEdit.js

   ```
    iconsPath : './nicEditorIcons.gif',
   ```

   to use @{Img_nicEditorIcons_gif} or with #{} did not work. (Gif is in static/img-dir and also on a number of other places now.)

   A partial answer is to use in nicEdit.js

   ```
    iconsPath : 'http://localhost:3000/static/img/nicEditorIcons.gif?etag=gUsMv6k-',
   ```

   Now the icons show up! However, this clumsy in the sense that it would be much better to let the widget (Field -function) to find out the etag-part automatically. Etag-part can be found from the source code of the web-page that didn't show the Icons.

   Actually, in nicEdit.js one can use either of the first two of the following and icon's will show up:

   ```
    iconsPath : './static/img/nicEditorIcons.gif',
    // iconsPath : 'http://localhost:3000/static/img/nicEditorIcons.gif',
    // iconsPath : './nicEditorIcons.gif',
   ```

   This is almost acceptable now. The only irritating thing still left is that as a library user, I still should edit the original source a bit.
2. What about the following handler:

   ```
   module Handler.Img_nicEditorIcons_gif where

   import Import
   getImg_nicEditorIcons_gif :: Handler RepHtml
   getImg_nicEditorIcons_gif = do 
       defaultLayout $ do
           -- $(widgetFile "img_nicEditorIcons_gif")
           -- [whamlet|@{StaticR img_nicEditorIcons_gif}|]
           [whamlet|<img src=@{StaticR img_nicEditorIcons_gif}>|]
   ```

   Now the server says:

   ```
    GET /blog
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    11/Jan/2013:22:05:09 +0200 [Debug#SQL] "SELECT \"id\",\"title\",\"content\" FROM     \"article\" ORDER BY \"title\" DESC" [] @(persistent-   1.1.3.2:Database.Persist.GenericSql.Raw ./Database/Persist/GenericSql/Raw.hs:121:12)
    Status: 200 OK. /blog
    GET /nicEditorIcons.gif
    Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
    Status: 200 OK. /nicEditorIcons.gif
   ```

   But the editor still does not find the icons. Route works, if put into the browser. Img-tag shows the icons nicely on a separate page. Similarly, if using StaticR, the icons can be found from the javascript part (a link in the footer), but not in editor...
3. Julius-case, also a partial success.

   As in the first case (static), by using

   ```
    iconsPath : 'http://localhost:3000/static/img/nicEditorIcons.gif',
   ```

   in the blog3.julius file, the icons showed up. In this case, blog3-handler in Handler/Blog3.hs is

   ```
    getBlog3R :: Handler RepHtml
    getBlog3R = do
      defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "Trial to find the icons"
        $(widgetFile "articles3")
        $(widgetFile "blog3")
        toWidget $ [julius|
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function(){new nicEditor({fullPanel:true}).panelInstance("h3")});
    |]
   ```

   Corresponding template/articles3.hamlet is

   ```
    <h1> Articles3
    $if null articles
      -- Show a standard message if there is no article
      <p> There are no articles in the blog
    $else
      -- Show the list of articles
      <ul>
        $forall Entity articleId article <- articles
          <li> 
             <a href=@{ArticleR articleId} > #{articleTitle article}
   ```

   File blog3.hamlet is

   ```
    <hr>
      <form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="8mFKLWnKcn">
        <div class="required ">
          <label for="h2">Title
          <input id="h2" name="f2" type="text" required value="">
        <div class="required ">
          <label for="h3">Content
          <textarea id="h3" name="f3">
        <div>
         <input type="submit" value="Post New Article">
   ```

   But as stated already, also in this solution there is a need to edit nicEdit.js sources a bit...

Even though this is almost solved, if anybody has a better alternative to this, I'd like hear about it... And case two above, I'll quess it's quite far from anything usable at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably is too late, but here is the answer:

new nicEditor( {iconsPath : "your_path"} )

Seen here: http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=2

Comment: I cannot check this now but it looks like a correct answer! Thanks!